# PHP - How to remove the substring starting with desired character?

Tags: php

Ok i have a random string comin from database like this

```
"Fruit Apple = 3 pcs"
```

sometime it can be

```
"Fruit Mangoes = 44 pcs ripe"
```

ok my question is **how can i remove the substring starting from equal (=) character ?**

```
like "= 3 pcs"
and "44 pcs ripe"
```

so the result string will be

```
Fruit Apple
```

or

```
Fruit Mangoes
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `$str= explode("=", $str)[0];`

Comment: Alright explode is the easy way.. thanks a lot to all who share their codes.. i tried all you codes it works fine.. but i prefer to choose explode function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use explode("=",$data) and you will get an array which contains left part in 0 index and right part on index 1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "Fruit Apple = 3 pcs";
$str = preg_replace('/\s*=.*/', '', $str);
print $str;
```

prints: Fruit Apple

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr(,,true)](http://docs.php.net/strstr) for that.
E.g.

```
<?php
$src = array(
    "Fruit Apple = 3 pcs",
    "Fruit Mangoes = 44 pcs ripe"
);

foreach($src as $e ) {
    echo strstr($e, '=', true), "\n";
}
```

prints

```
Fruit Apple 
Fruit Mangoes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, even some people consider its a performance hit in the modern day computers

```
$str = "Fruit Mangoes = 44 pcs ripe";
$str = preg_replace("/\s=.*$/", "", $str);
```